# Restoring sound drivers on Debian 8

Tags: debian, drivers, audio, nvidia

I have installed Nvidia graphic drivers for my Debian 8, but the installation contained a new sound driver, which has broken the sound on my PC.
How can I uninstall the Nvidia one and restore the default Debian 8 sound drivers?

EDIT: 
My lsmod output:

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    12927  3 
ccm                    17577  3 
nfsd                  263032  2 
auth_rpcgss            51211  1 nfsd
oid_registry           12419  1 auth_rpcgss
nfs_acl                12511  1 nfsd
nfs                   188136  0 
lockd                  83389  2 nfs,nfsd
fscache                45542  1 nfs
sunrpc                237402  6 nfs,nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
nvidia              10516047  25 
uvcvideo               79005  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12816  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       12519  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         47787  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            12995  1 videobuf2_core
joydev                 17063  0 
videodev              126451  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  18305  2 uvcvideo,videodev
arc4                   12536  2 
ath9k                  90244  0 
ath9k_common           21746  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              391172  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    26067  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              474277  1 ath9k
snd_hda_codec_realtek    67127  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    63181  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
coretemp               12820  0 
psmouse                99249  0 
pcspkr                 12595  0 
evdev                  17445  26 
asus_laptop            26861  0 
snd_hda_intel          26327  4 
cfg80211              405538  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
sparse_keymap          12818  1 asus_laptop
snd_hda_controller     26646  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         104463  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
serio_raw              12849  0 
snd_hwdep              13148  1 snd_hda_codec
drm                   249955  3 nvidia
snd_pcm_oss            44798  0 
rfkill                 18867  3 cfg80211,asus_laptop
input_polldev          13118  1 asus_laptop
snd_mixer_oss          22042  1 snd_pcm_oss
i2c_nforce2            12591  0 
i2c_core               46012  5 drm,nvidia,v4l2_common,i2c_nforce2,videodev
snd_pcm                88662  4 snd_pcm_oss,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_timer              26614  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65244  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm_oss,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_mixer_oss
soundcore              13026  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
video                  18096  0 
ac                     12715  0 
shpchp                 31121  0 
wmi                    17339  0 
battery                13356  0 
button                 12944  0 
acpi_cpufreq           17218  1 
processor              28221  3 acpi_cpufreq
fuse                   83350  1 
parport_pc             26300  0 
ppdev                  16782  0 
lp                     17074  0 
parport                35749  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                35529  2 
hid_generic            12393  0 
usbhid                 44460  0 
hid                   102264  3 hid_generic,usbhid
ext4                  473802  1 
crc16                  12343  1 ext4
mbcache                17171  1 ext4
jbd2                   82413  1 ext4
sd_mod                 44356  3 
sg                     29973  0 
crc_t10dif             12431  1 sd_mod
crct10dif_generic      12581  1 
sr_mod                 21903  0 
cdrom                  47424  1 sr_mod
crct10dif_common       12356  2 crct10dif_generic,crc_t10dif
ata_generic            12490  0 
ahci                   33291  2 
ohci_pci               12808  0 
libahci                27158  1 ahci
libata                177457  3 ahci,libahci,ata_generic
r8169                  68262  0 
mii                    12675  1 r8169
scsi_mod              191405  4 sg,libata,sd_mod,sr_mod
thermal                17559  0 
thermal_sys            27642  3 video,thermal,processor
ehci_pci               12512  0 
ohci_hcd               42982  1 ohci_pci
ehci_hcd               69837  1 ehci_pci
usbcore               195340  6 uvcvideo,ohci_hcd,ohci_pci,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid
usb_common             12440  1 usbcore
```

Comment: Some more information might help here: /proc/asound/cards and devices, something like `lsmod | grep snd`,... It is possible, that you just need to select a different "default sound card" somewhere in your Desktop environment.

Comment: Ok, added lsmod.

Comment: use `| grep snd` to filter the output. Prepend the output from `cat /proc/asound/cards`

Comment: Result: http://pastebin.com/fW3XTUeM

Answer (score 1):

**I have found the solution:**

I needed to install the **alsa-oss** with **apt-get install alsa-oss**.

For being able to use my headset too, I needed to install the **alsamixergui** with **apt-get install alsamixergui**.

You can take a look at it's description on this site: https://wiki.debian.org/ALSA